# Unexpected results from styling a select element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a `select` element but I get unexpected results.

First, when an `option` element is overflowed, I cannot view the whole 4 options at once. There is a vertical scroll when `option` element is being overflowed (but if it wouldn't - I could see the whole 4 options).

Secondly, you can see that when you choose either of the `option` elements, the background is not `100%` of the whole `select` element (and I consider the `select` element width to consist of the scroll extra width).

Thirdly.. You can choose the 4th `option` element and see that once you choose it part of the element text is hidden.

How can I fix these problems?

```css
.x {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.y {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select class="x" size="4">
  <option class="y">Test</option>
  <option class="y">Test</option>
  <option class="y">Test</option>
  <option class="y">Test Test Test Test  Test Test Test Test</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, what is your expected output actually? What are you trying to do?

Comment: don't use specific width use min-width instead.

Comment: Is this an answer or comment?

Comment: @TalRofe It's a answer in comment I guess, but still I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, for me it seems working.

Comment: @BhaweshVerma I can't find where am I not enough explicit so please tell me what part did not you understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css you find here for this: https://github.com/filamentgroup/select-css/blob/master/src/select-css.css

But I would recommend to style a frame around the select meny instead, with a class of .select-frame for example. It's a bit easier to deal with and guarantees that it looks the same on all platforms until you click it (the native options list is then displayed).